# remove ids generated during the tests

Tags: javascript, k6

For load testing in the `vu` stage I generate a lot of objects with unique ids that I put them in the database. I want to delete them during `teardown` stage in order not to pollute the database.

When keeping the state like this

```
let ids = [];
export function setup() {
    ids.push('put in setup id');
}

export default function () {
    ids.push('put in vu id');
}

export function teardown() {
    ids.push('put in teardown id');
    console.log('Resources: ' + ids);
}
```

it doesn't work as the array always contains the data I put in `teardown` stage.

Passing data between stages also doesn't work due to well-know `Cannot extend Go slice` issue, but even with that, you cannot pass the data from `vu` stage to `teardown` as it always gets the data from `setup` stage.

The only remaining solution is either playing around with `console log` or just use a plain preset of ids and use them in tests. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setup()`, `teardown()`, and the VUs' `default` functions are executed in completely different JavaScript runtimes. For distributed execution, they may be executed on completely different machines. So you can't just have a global `ids` variable that you're able to access from everywhere.

That limitation is the reason why you're supposed to return any data you care about from `setup()` - k6 will copy it and pass it as a parameter to the `default` function (so you can use whatever resources you set up) and `teardown()` (so you can clean them up).

Your example has to look somewhat like this:

```
export function setup() {
    let ids = [];
    ids.push('put in setup id');
    return ids;
}

export default function (ids) {
    // you cannot push to ids here
    console.log('Resources: ' + ids);
}

export function teardown(ids) {
    console.log('Resources: ' + ids);
}
```

You can find more information at https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/test-life-cycle

Comment: so basically I have to decouple ID generation from the vu stage?

Comment: yes, that's probably the easiest and cleanest option

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @na--'s answer, I propose an external workaround using Redis and [Webdis](https://webd.is/) to manage the IDs.

It's actually quite simple, if you don't mind running an additional process, and shouldn't impact performance greatly:

1. Start a Webdis/Redis container:
   `docker run --rm -it -p 127.0.0.1:7379:7379 nicolas/webdis`
2. `script.js`:

```js
import http from 'k6/http';

const url = "http://127.0.0.1:7379/"

export function setup() {
    const ids = [1, 2, 3];
    for (let id of ids) {
        http.post(url, `LPUSH/ids/${id}`);
    }
}

export default function () {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    http.post(url, `LPUSH/ids/${id}`);
}

export function teardown() {
    let res = http.get(`${url}LRANGE/ids/0/-1`);
    let ids = JSON.parse(res.body)['LRANGE'];
    for (let id of ids) {
        console.log(id);
    }
    // cleanup
    http.post(url, 'DEL/ids');
}
```

3. Run 5 iterations with:
   `k6 run -i 5 script.js`

Example output:

```
INFO[0000] 7
INFO[0000] 2
INFO[0000] 2
INFO[0000] 6
INFO[0000] 5
INFO[0000] 3
INFO[0000] 2
INFO[0000] 1
```

A drawback of this solution is that it will skew the overall test results, because of the additional HTTP requests that are not relevant to the test itself. There might be a way to exclude these with tags, otherwise it would be a good feature request. :)

Using a Node.js Redis client to avoid HTTP requests could be an alternative, but those libraries usually aren't "browserifiable" so they likely wouldn't work in k6.

Comment: It's insane that k6 cannot fix this in a simple manner.

Comment: @basickarl That's because it's not a simple problem that can be solved for all use cases. As na-- explained, the exported functions run in different JS runtimes and potentially in different processes or different machines in distributed execution. It requires some centralized process to synchronize the state, and Redis is one approach. Though with the introduction of k6 extensions, keeping a global counter within a single k6 process is possible with https://github.com/MStoykov/xk6-counter , so I suppose something similar could be done for shared global state.